# Convert string into url

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurl

I am getting something when I convert string to NSURL.
My code id...

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://host name/index.php?id=%@&mob=%@&name=%@&mail=%@&m=23", self.deviceId, self.pnumber, self.name, self.email];
urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSURL *urlPattern = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSLog(@"%@", urlPattern);

http://host name/index.php?dev_id=73EA1D1D-E6E3-485C-883D-DF952E116&mob=%3CUITextField:%200x7fe247063c00;%20frame%20=%20(0%20128.333;%20310.667%2040.6667);%20text%20=%20'';%20opaque%20=%20NO;%20autoresize%20=%20RM+BM;%20gestureRecognizers%20=%20%3CNSArray:%200x608000244c50%3E;%20layer%20=%20%3CCALayer:%200x60800003eee0%3E%3E&name=%3CUITextField:%200x7fe247055800;%20frame%20=%20(0%2044;%20310.667%2040.3333);%20text%20=%20'';%20opaque%20=%20NO;%20autoresize%20=%20RM+BM;%20gestureRecognizers%20=%20%3CNSArray:%200x608000244410%3E;%20layer%20=%20%3CCALayer:%200x60800003e240%3E%3E&mail=%3CUITextField:%200x7fe24601ae00;%20frame%20=%20(0%20213;%20310.667%2040.3333);%20text%20=%20'';%20opaque%20=%20NO;%20autoresize%20=%20RM+BM;%20gestureRecognizers%20=%20%3CNSArray:%200x608000243c90%3E;%20layer%20=%20%3CCALayer:%200x60c000038580%3E%3E&m=23
```

How to convert string to NSURL

Comment: What is the issue are you getting?

Comment: your code is fine and correct what the issue u faced

Comment: you encoded your nsstring and you have converted that nsstring to nsurl in the above code. what is your requirement ?

Comment: I am getting this http://host name/index.php?dev_id=73EA1D1D-E6E3-485C-883D-DF952E116&mob=%3CUITextField:%200x7fe247063c00;%20frame%20=%20(0%20128.333;%20310.667%2040.6667);%20text%20=%20'';%20opaque%20=%20NO;%20autoresize%20=%20RM+BM;%20gestureRecognizers%20=%20%3CNSArray:%200x608000244c50%3E;%20layer%20=%20%3CCALayer:%200x60800003eee0%3E%3E&name=%3CUITextField:%200x7fe247055800;%20frame%20=%20(0%2044;  But it's not working...Is it correct na

Comment: @iOSDeveloper you send a textfiled in url.so check and send textfiled text not textfiled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you are assigning textfield to urlString. Check for self.pnumber whether its a textfield or string. If textField then set as self.pnumber.text and similarly check for all data.

change `self.pnumber, self.name, self.email` to `self.pnumber.text, self.name.text, self.email.text`

use like

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://host name/index.php?id=%@&mob=%@&name=%@&mail=%@&m=23", self.deviceId, self.pnumber.text, self.name.text, self.email.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

let NSHipster  = URL(string: "http://nshipster.com/")                 //returns a valid URL

let invalidURL = URL(string: "www.example.com/This is a sentence")    //Returns nil

for more detail:
http://www.codingexplorer.com/creating-and-modifying-nsurl-in-swift/